# Clicking a button on one form while clicking on a different form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two programs, both in different namespaces, which run independently of each other. I would like to call the click event of a button on one form if it is being executed by clicking a button on the other.

I was able to do this in VB by making the form `public`, referencing the **dll** in form2 and calling the click from `namespace.form1.button_click` but can't work out how to do it in C#.

Comment: "two programs"???? are you sure these two forms are in different programs or are they different forms of the same program?

Comment: Definitely two programs. Both are of type ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000000w2000000

Comment: and how are you starting these application? I mean are they getting started independently or through some application from which we can get a reference to each other application

Comment: They are buttons on the ArcGIS application. One is ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.Button (form1) the other is ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.Tool (form2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to pass a reference of form2 object (*which is run by clicking on the button to launch it in ArcGIS application*) to form1 object.

If form2 is a separate add-in (*provided by a third party*) and does not expose any API functions, then I think it is pretty difficult to achieve what you want. If you have created this add-in, then you can expose a function so that other applications can invoke the button click on this add-in.

Also, the mode of communication between the two add-ins also depends on how add-ins are loaded in ArcGIS application (in-process or out-process). Depending on that, you could either directly call the other function or you may need to go through remoting, RPC, etc

***The above response is based on my understanding about how to invoke button click of another add-in and may not be relevant to this specific case. Kindly provide more detail about the environment, who created the add-ins, etc***

**Edit: below added after OP's comment**

As you have code to both the projects and can update them, that's good, we can do whatever we want

After passing reference of form2 object to form1, form1 will be able to access all methods of System.Windows.Forms.Form only (even if you make button_click public in form2, it will not be accessible)

Create a new project, which will act as base (prjBase) and contains an interface IOutsideCallable

```
interface IOutsideCallable {
     void PerformButtonClick();
}
```

Now, in your projects of form1 and form2 add reference to the above project
Implement the above interface in form2

```
class Form2: System.Windows.Forms.Form, IOutsideCallable {
    // other form code

    public void PerformButtonClick() {
        btn_Click(null, null);
    }
}
```

In form1, create a variable to point to object of type IOutsideCallable. You can pass the form2 object either in constructor of form1 or through a property. (As you mentioned in your comment that you don't know the order in which constructors are passed, you can use the property)

So, in form1

```
class Form1: System.Windows.Forms.Form {
    // form1 code

    public IOutsideCallable Form2Variable { get; set; }

    void foo() { // the function in which you will invoke the button click of Form2
        if(Form2Variable != null) Form2Variable.PerformButtonClick();
    }
}
```

Comment: I created both add-ins, I'll give that a shot. So when I launch form1 I need to give a reference to it to form2 before that form is launched - that sounds fair, it's like how I get a reference to the calling application to set the public bool FormIsShown to true and then false on form close to ensure not more than one form is shown. Both forms have their constructors called on application startup but I'm not sure in what order; perhaps pass the reference on button click not during construction. Thanks.

Comment: The answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920006/firing-a-method-in-form-1-on-click-of-a-button-on-form2?rq=1 I should have googled more before I asked the question. I like your method @ManishDalal however I came across the simpler method while looking on how to pass a reference from one form to another.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson: The method you found is good but will work only for if both forms are in same application. As you mentioned that these are separate add-ins, so I suggested above method. Actually, whenever you need to access form2, you will need to have access to its type to call functions & properties which are specific to form2 (by default you can call only call functions and properties of base class). In other question, you can see that you are typecasting to type form1 [((Form1)form).Close()], you can do this as both forms are in the same application. Anyway happy coding (y)

Answer (score 0):

First change the access modifier of form2 contractor to private And the button_click method to public.

Then Add this code to Form2 class:

```
    private static Form2 _Instance;
    public static Form2 Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_Instance == null)
                _Instance = new Form2();

            return _Instance;
        }
    }
```

Now you can call the buuton_click in form2 from button_click in form1 like this:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2.Instance.button1_Click(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
```

Comment: this code will cause the button click of the form2 which is not displayed, but in memory only

Comment: Is that creating or executing form1 from form2? It is important that form1 is independent of form2. Normally form1 would exist before form2 is run - Form1 is essentially a counter which I want to increment the existing count by pressing a button on form2.